# How to split and orthomosaic into a grid / index polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I would like to know is there a way to split a large Orthomosaic of an area into equal grids of 10 meters each?[image: Ortho with grids]

Sofar i have tried the " split raster" tool under " raster processing "[[image: the split raster parameters/settings], but this does not work, it indicates that the output was successful, but the folder is empty.

I am using ArcGIS desktop 10.5.

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the settings you used for both tools.

Comment: @Erik Thank you, I have attached screenshots.